# Django send email: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: python, django, email

I am trying to send a test email in Django with "send_email" function but I'm getting an exception of
"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting EMAIL_BACKEND, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings." Via py shell however everything works.

I have tried to set "set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings" (Windows), and include it in PyCharm Env Variables and also run "django-admin dbshell --settings mysite.settings".

The last produced an exception ModuleNotFoundError.

I cannot get what is the problem, sending email via python smtp lib works and via Django does not.

Comment: Can you please share your backend email settings code.

Comment: This question has been answered. Search please

Comment: you have to set backend in `settings.py` - see doc for [EMAIL_BACKEND](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#obtaining-an-instance-of-an-email-backend)